# Restore all DB backups in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-backups, database-restore

I change my OS to Windows 11 and want restore all backup files at once. I wrote this query

```
DECLARE @FilesCmdshell TABLE (outputCmd NVARCHAR (255))

DECLARE @FilesCmdshellCursor CURSOR
DECLARE @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd AS NVARCHAR(255)
 
INSERT INTO @FilesCmdshell (outputCmd) 
    EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell 'dir /B  E:\Projects\SQLBackup\*.bak'

SET @FilesCmdshellCursor = CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT outputCmd FROM @FilesCmdshell
 
OPEN @FilesCmdshellCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM @FilesCmdshellCursor INTO @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + '] FROM DISK = N''E:\Projects\SQLBackup\' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + '.bak'' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10'
    EXEC(@cmd)
 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @FilesCmdshellCursor INTO @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd
END
```

But when I run it, I get several errors:

> Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.HMNFRK\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2019.mdf'.
>
> Msg 3156, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
> File 'AdventureWorks2017' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.HMNFRK\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2019.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.

I run SSMS as administrator.

Comment: How you run SSMS is not relevant, you need to make sure the service account you run Sql Server under has the correct NTFS permissions on the folder containing the backups.

Comment: how can i make sure ?

Comment: `RESTORE` can and should be fully parameterized, so you don't need all that horrible dynamic SQL

Comment: It's in the Properties of the Directory, @Houman . Right click the Directory, or select it and press `Alt`+`Enter`, and then go to the Security Pane to see what accounts have access to it; and what they can do. Ensure that the service account SQL Server is running under has access to both the location the backups are located in *and* the locations the database(s) are being restored to.

Comment: Definitely a permission issue, whatever account you are using doesn't have full access to the folders your trying to pull from. Change those permissions and it should work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue related to folder permission, You need to set "everyone" with Full control to resolve this issue

[image]

Comment: Hi ShafirR. Granting full permission to everyone seems like an overly broad permission.

Comment: Note: In a "real world" environment, I would highly recommend **against** giving *everyone* access to the directory your database files are in. For a local, sandboxing environment, it is (at best) "ok", but not  for anything more than that (I would even say that it's not "ok" for a local dev environment). You should be giving the AD Groups, and AD Service account(s), which would include the one running SQL Server's Service account, that *need* access to the directory access, and no more.